# pfSense NAT routing using VLANs

Tags: nat, vlan, pfsense

We already have pfSense installed and it is working for our single IP address on 1.1.1.1. We also have a further 3 ip addresses (1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3, 1.1.1.4) which are set up as VLANs on the WAN interface.

- WAN => 1.1.1.1
- VLAN2 => 1.1.1.2
- VLAN3 => 1.1.1.2
- VLAN4 => 1.1.1.2

All 4 of these have a ping response. However, if I look to connect through other ports (SMTP on 25) then I am forwarded to the WAN address no matter which address I connect to.

At the moment we have NAT rules set up to port forward from:

- WAN (port 25) => 192.168.0.1
- VLAN2 (port 25) => 192.168.0.2
- VLAN3 (port 25) => 192.168.0.3
- VLAN4 (port 25) => 192.168.0.4

So if I "telnet 1.1.1.2 25" then I get a response from 1.1.1.1 (WAN) instead of 1.1.1.2 VLAN2. NAT outbound is set to **Manual**.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Or just what to try next as we are at a bit of a loss with what to try next.

Comment: Are you sure that you need VLAN's? You might just need a secondary IP Address on the WAN interface...

Comment: The WAN interface gets it IP address from PPPoE. We can't see how you could have 1 WAN interface with multiple IP addresses?

Comment: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/What_are_Virtual_IP_Addresses see "IP Alias" there